# Meteor "502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoints failed to handle the request." error - Galaxy

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to deploy to Galaxy (using MLab as my mongo DB). It seems to deploy fine, but I get a 502 error.

I know that sometimes it can be due to a connection problem on the mlab side but I'm able to connect to my db through the mongo shell.

Anyone have any ideas? (p.s. - upgraded to the latest version of meteor and can run on localhost so I don't think it's that).

Comment: Im having a same issue but only when uploading files. Hard to debug. I'll let you know if i find a solution.

Comment: Yes, it's now working. In my case it seemed to be two things, one was a corrupt container and the other was the connection to mongo lab. If you want a great walk through of how to set this up one of the guys in our NYC Meteor group created an easy to follow guide... http://coderchronicles.org/2016/03/15/deploying-a-meteor-app-to-galaxy/

Comment: Thanks! The problem was when uploading files using cfs:s3 etc. I changed to another library, because that worked my localhost but not in galaxy.

Comment: Ah yeah - the cfs file collection - I had a lot of experience with CollectionFS - the problem is that depending on where you managed it they would get wiped out. (In other words if it existed in your main and not internal meteor file system). You actually have to put it into .meteor/local/cfs in order to work and then essentially you create pointers and store those. So for example am image would be images-KLkcibicjxEZXQs9L-NH1nLsV.jpg. Anyway it got complicated.